# CSS overflow:scroll doesn't work only for iFrame in Chrome, Safari and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opera

I am using `overflow:scroll;` in my css to have scrollbars always "on" for an iFrame window, but it works **only** for Firefox! Any idea about Chrome, Safari and Opera? Thank you in advance!

Comment: duplicated question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054772/overflow-sroll-doesnt-work-in-chrome

Comment: Have you set a height on your iFrame?

Comment: @Billy Moat: Yes but not through css etc. It take's it's high from option. I am talking about the Modal Box in Joomla 1.5

Comment: @anvd: I know it's duplicated question. I inform administrators to delete the other one!!! Thank you...

Comment: @GreenMadness you **need** to provide sample code with the question to help people understand your problem. If you can reproduce your issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) then that also benefits your question

Comment: @My Head Hurts: OK thank you!!! I'll try to put it on this JSFiddle and I'll be back...

Comment: Here is the code... http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/hSHRf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar issue with webkit (safari and chrome) based browsers; seems that they value  higher the css styles on the html over the actual iframe style itself. Can´t find much documentation on this, but I am sure it is the origin of the problem.

http://trafficonweb.com/iframe-moves.png the iframe moves to left when pulled right on its main content (under the navigation menu). Only on webkit.

This happens when scaling down the iframe with the scale (transform) css property.

This is not the perfect answer but at least a hint; will continue research and post afterwards.

And looking for others to contribute to this issue. Thanks.